# Compare Sales with last year sales per customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum, union

I have a 2 queries that I have used UNION on to compare the sales value per customer over 2 years. The below returns 2 columns, one for organizations and one for the sales value/customer. But the 2 year split is not working. It seems to be pulling all the values into one column rather than having a column for 2018 and a column for 2019. Maybe I should be using a join or a sub-query?

The return result would look something like:

```
Organization    Last Year      Previous year
CUS                 12000        160000
etc
```

```
SELECT Top 25
    FORMAT(SUM(dbo.ARInvoices.arpFullInvoiceSubtotalBase), 'C2') AS "previousyear ", dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID AS "Organization"
FROM (dbo.ARInvoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.ARInvoices.arpCustomerOrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID)  
WHERE  YEAR(arpInvoiceDate) = year(DATEADD(year, -2, getdate()))AND arpInvoiceType = 1
GROUP BY dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID

UNION

SELECT Top 25
    FORMAT(SUM(dbo.ARInvoices.arpFullInvoiceSubtotalBase), 'C2') AS "Lastyear", dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID AS "Organization"
FROM (dbo.ARInvoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.ARInvoices.arpCustomerOrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID)   
WHERE  YEAR(arpInvoiceDate) = year(DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()))AND arpInvoiceType = 1
GROUP BY dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do conditional aggregation

```
select
    sum(case 
        when arpInvoiceDate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 2, 1, 1) 
             and arpInvoiceDate < datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1) 
        then i.arpFullInvoiceSubtotalBase
    end) as previousYear,
    sum(case 
        when arpInvoiceDate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1)
        then i.arpFullInvoiceSubtotalBase
    end) as lastYear
from dbo.ARInvoices i 
inner join dbo.Organizations o ON i.arpCustomerOrganizationID = o.cmoOrganizationID
where arpInvoiceType = 1 and arpInvoiceDate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 2, 1, 1)
group by o.cmoOrganizationID
```

Notes:

- I used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` since one of the columns for the left table is used in the `GROUP BY` clause
- table aliases do make the query shorter to write and easier to read
- I changed the implementation of the date filtering so no date function is used on the table columns (this makes the query more efficient)

Comment: thank you @GMB How would I then include the customer name as a column as well?